# How to make realistic pockets of sand?

Tags: texturing, materials, procedural

I want to add sand around the small rocks in this scene but I'm not sure the best way to go about it.

[image]

Ideally, I'd love to increase the rocks by millions, but obviously that would increase the poly count like crazy.  Is there a way to add sand/gravel without looking like blobs with noise texture?

Here's a reference I am using:

[image]

Comment: Could you post some reference images?

Comment: Good idea.  OK I have posted the reference photo.

Comment: I think you would find [blenderguru's Make Mars tutorial](https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/make-mars) interesting.

Comment: That's actually what I was following but I had to modify it to have more rocks and be in a valley...and also to use my own rocks instead of the "rock essentials" which he tries to make you buy :) But it's a good tutorial though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform this in several ways: you can create a particle system, you can UV paint where you want the sand (with a sand texture image), you can paint influence areas to switch from selected textures or you can make Blender automatically blend two (or more) textures based on your model geometry (height, normals, etc). The following node setup shows an easy way where i use model's height to blend a gravel image with a grass image (higher levels of topography have grass, lower levels have gravel). You can control the blend position by controling the color ramp, and you can control the image scale on the Mapping Node's point scale. I've remembered this solution because in your reference image, the sand is always at lowest height levels. You can switch raster textures with procedural textures.[image][image]

Comment: This is an interesting and good method, but how would I be able to make convincing textures up close like the reference photo I posted?  Is there a way to make it less poly when the camera is far and higher poly when it's close?

Comment: if I understood correctly, you just need to play with the scale of the textures. You can fake 3D small details, ripples or dunes with a to scale bumpmap or normal map. You can attach a bump texture to a bump node, then connect it to the diffuse nodes (example a single diffuse node will have a color texture, like RGB or procedural, and a bump map with faked 3D detail).

Comment: as about increasing resolution based on distance (also known as level of detail), you can search tutorials on microdisplacements - like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dRzzaRvVDng)

Comment: about what i said earlier, dont forget to connect the mapping node to the bump texture you use, so it keeps scale no matter the distance

Comment: Sorry for the super late reply...took me a long time to get it just right.  Totally worked though thanks!

Comment: that's great :)